# Correct way to share object in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, oop, server, sinatra

I have a small situation here:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'someclass'

['/endpoint1', '/endpoint2', '/endpoint3'].each do |path|
  before path do
    @obj = Someclass.new
  end

get '/endpoint1' do
  @obj.somefunction
end

# similar for other endpoints
```

What is the better way:

1. make new object for every request? OR
2. make an object globally at the start of server and use it for all requests?

What are pros/cons of the same?

Answer (score 2):

1. uses a bit more memory and stresses the garbage collector more, but you have no concurrency concerns to worry about in your object.
2. uses a bit less memory, but means your object needs to be thread-safe.

Unless you have a compelling need to have a single instance of this object, or its construction is expensive, I would go with 1. until it is no longer feasible.

Comment: How thread-safe? If I am using common object then the function will be bind to it...pls correct me if I am wrong.